# Android recent apps

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a strange problem with my app. On my HTC One X max apps in recent apps is 9 and if my app gets pushed out of these 9 apps when I start it again it acts weird and breaks in all kinds of ways.

In my BaseActivity OnRestart I have code that switches current activity to main activity. This doesn't happen in above scenario.

```
 protected override void OnRestart()
 {
        base.OnRestart();

        if(someTimeHasPassed)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            // Kills every open activity to disable user from going back.
            finishAllOpenActivities();
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
  }
```

I'm not sure what part of code to post. Anyone had any similar issues?

EDIT: After the above scenario happens

```
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
```

in OnCreate() never executes because when I press home button I can see my app normally, no black screen. And by normally I can see the background and default header with activity name, nothing else gets loaded.

Not sure why OnCreate is even being called because I'm returning to that screen.

EDIT 2: After more examination, this seems to happen when some apps are in front of mine in recent apps. Could this be a memory issue?

Comment: Try to expand on " breaks in all kinds of ways" - include screenshots, error messages etc. It's a life-cycle issue, but without knowing more we can't help you!

Comment: @JoeyJubb I added some more description.